# Error converting data type varchar to numeric. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing data on the Sql Server database. 
When data is written, a trigger runs.

---

TRIGGER

```
ALTER TRIGGER Alert ON records AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @tempmin decimal = 0
DECLARE @current_max_idAlarm int = (SELECT MAX(IdAlarm) FROM alarms)
DECLARE @maxidAlarm int
DECLARE @temp decimal = (SELECT s.lim_inf_temp  from sensores s JOIN inserted i ON s.idSensor=i.idSensor )

-- Insert into alares from the inserted rows if temperature less than tempmin
SET IDENTITY_INSERT alarmes On
INSERT alarmes (IdAlarm, desc_alarm,date, idRecord)
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.idRecord) + @current_max_idAlarm, 'Temp Error', GETDATE(), i.idRecord
    FROM
inserted AS i
    WHERE
i.Temperature < @temp

end
```

---

INSERT

```
insert into record values ('2014-05-26' ,'14:51:47','Sensor01','---','48.6','9.8');
```

Whenever I try to record this type of data: '---'

Gives the following error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure Alert, Line 
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

I know it is to be in decimal type (DECLARE @temp decimal - TRIGGER), but moving to the type varchar to trigger stops working correctly.

Does someone can help me resolve this error please?

Thank you all.

Comment: Why do you want to insert `---`? you realize it's commenting out?

Comment: Thanks for reply.Because I am recording the data through a parser from a txt file. 
And sometimes a few data comes in this format ---

Comment: You can help me @meda ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert `---` inside a numeric column, you simply can't do that.

You have mainly 2 options:

- Change the data type of the destination column
- Choose a different value to insert (like NULL)

Comment: Thanks for reply. The type is varchar. But in DECLARE @ temp is decimal to do the comparison   WHERE i.Temperature < @ temp. If I change the type, like DECLARE @ temp varchar the trigger stops working correctly.

Comment: That's because you need to cast the variable at the right datatype when you do the comparison: i.Temperature < CAST(@Temp AS DECIMAL). Anyway from what you provided in the question, the error seems to be on the insert. You are trying to convert --- as numeric, and that's not possible. All the other values works because of implicit conversions.

Comment: The insert runs fine if I don't have a trigger. So it is said that the problem is in the trigger statement. I tried what you said, but give me the same error :S

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems I cannot help you :(

Comment: I will acept your answer because help me to think and found a solution to my problem ;)